# Calculating Big-O from given algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm currently studying for my exams where one of the questions will be calculating the big-o from a given algorithm. One of the questions from last year goes like:

---

```
T_compute(n) ∈ O(n)
```

Algorithm:

```
void func2(const int n) {
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      compute(i);
}
```

What is the timecomplexity of func2? T_func2(n) ∈

---

Now the solution says that the time complexity is

```
T_func2(n) ∈ O(n/2(n-1))
```

Can anyone explain to me how they got to this solution?

Comment: I don't know how they arrived at the exact expression, but clearly the behavior is `O(n^2)` and the smaller terms do not matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since we know the complexity of `compute(n)` to be `O(n)`, we can, without loss of generality, analyze the complexity of `func2(n)` under the assumption that `compute(n) = n`, i.e.

```
T_func2(n) ∝ sum_{i = 1 to n} compute(i) 
           = sum_{i = 1 to n} i
           = n(n+1)/2
```

Where in the last step we've used [this summation rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn).

Now, we could say that `T_func2 ∈ O(n(n+1)/2)` (I will assume that `n(n-1)` is a typo on your behalf), but this is just `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! This really helped me. But I didn't do a typo at the solution. Maybe my Professor did it

Comment: @whileFalse happy to help. The exact value of the sum above does not hold any real value to us as we're analyzing complexity and working under an assumption (`compute(n) = n`) that is only sensible w.r.t. complexity analysis of `func2` (and not w.r.t. actual iteration count of `func2`).

Comment: @whileFalse (also note that if the loop where to use strict inequality, `i < n`, the the sum above would equal `n(n-1)/2`, possibly this explains the discrepancy)